# TextView Vertical Gravity not working in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, uiscrollview

First time posting here. Sorry if this has already been asked. I searched for days, and while some posts seemed relevant, they did not seem to address my exact issue.

I have a RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView. Inside the RelativeLayout, I have some TextViews. I have set the TextView gravities to center_vertical. Everything works fine when the page's contents fit on a single page without the need to activate the ScrollView. However, whenever the content exceeds the page and the ScrollView gets activated, the center_vertical gravity gets ignored. The funny thing is, the left/right (start/end) gravities are not being ignored, only the center_vertical ones.

Here's the main part of my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cup1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/cup1"
        android:textColor="#21386f"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/Space1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/cup1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/canadienslogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/Space1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/canadienslogo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/canadienslogo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/canadienslogo"
        android:layout_below="@id/Space1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="16sp"
        android:paddingRight="16sp"
        android:text="@string/score1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team_canadiens"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/canadienslogo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/canadienslogo"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/canadienslogo"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/score1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/canadienslogo"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/score1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:paddingLeft="2sp"
        android:paddingRight="2sp"
        android:text="@string/team_canadiens"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rosebudslogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/Space1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/rosebudslogo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team_rosebuds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/rosebudslogo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/rosebudslogo"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/score1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rosebudslogo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/score1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/rosebudslogo"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:paddingLeft="2sp"
        android:paddingRight="2sp"
        android:text="@string/team_rosebuds"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Below this, there is another Space followed by a TableLayout. If the table is too big to fit on a single page, the center_vertical gravity above gets ignored. The gravity does not appear to be affected within the table.

Here are two screenshots of the issue. The first has the issue, the second does not (because all the contents fit on a single page)...

[Issue](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/107043009/Android/Media/Images/Screenshots/Screenshot_2015-04-17-09-03-58.png)

[No Issue](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/107043009/Android/Media/Images/Screenshots/Screenshot_2015-04-17-09-04-05.png)

Notice how the text "Montreal Canadiens" "3 - 2" and "Portland Rosebuds" gets moved up. The center_vertical gravity is not being applied.

For the record, I only took screenshots in landscape mode because it would force ScrollView to kick in and show the issue. If I were to have bigger tables, the same issue occurs in portrait mode as well, so it's not an orientation issue. I've modified my code countless times but nothing seems to fix it. I'm sure it's something simple, I just can't figure it out. It might have something to do with the overall density of the height, since that's really the only thing that changes when ScrollView kicks in. I enabled the "Show layout bounds" under Developer Options and the actual containers are fine, it's just the contents that get pushed up. The weird thing is, both Eclipse and Android Studio do not show the issue in Design Mode. FWIW, I've tested it on my Galaxy Nexus and a Galaxy Tab 3 Lite, same thing occurs on both.

Hopefully one of you can make me look foolish and resolve it promptly.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Regards,

EDIT: New working code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cup1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/cup1"
        android:textColor="#21386f"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/Space1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/canadienslogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
            android:src="@drawable/canadienslogo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_canadiens"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:paddingLeft="2sp"
            android:paddingRight="2sp"
            android:text="@string/team_canadiens"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/score1"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_rosebuds"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:paddingLeft="2sp"
            android:paddingRight="2sp"
            android:text="@string/team_rosebuds"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rosebudslogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
            android:src="@drawable/rosebudslogo" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cannot say that it will solve your problem but you have a few quirks:

```
android:id="@+id/score1"
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/canadienslogo"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/canadienslogo"
```

You cannot align both `bottom` and `top`. if you want to match the height of 2 Views - then give them an height

another layout with the same issue:

```
android:id="@+id/team_canadiens"
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/canadienslogo"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/canadienslogo"
android:layout_toEndOf="@id/canadienslogo"
```

Comment: Hi royB, Thanks for the quick reply. I tried your suggestion, but I had to change my layout from Relative to Linear. In LinearLayout, I was able to match the height of the TextViews with that of the image by choosing wrap_content for the image height and match_parent for the text height. The problem I'm now having is that the actual score text (3 - 2) can no longer be placed in the absolute center of the width because there is no center_horizontal or centerInParent in a linear view.

Comment: Alright, I removed some of my excessive padding and added layout_weights to the 3 TextViews and I seem to be getting somewhere! Thanks royB!